# DNS Forwarding or Nameservers

Tags: domain-name, web-hosting, nameserver

I have a couple of domains registered with one company and then websites hosted with another.  One of the domains has nameservers pointing at the web host, the other has DNS forwarding to the same web host.  As far as I can tell there is no obvious effect on the running of the two websites (hobby sites with little traffic).

I'm in the process of moving to a new web host, and am wondering the pros and cons of using Nameservers vs DNS forwarding to point my domain to my web host?

[image]

My web-host recommends using their nameservers to point the domain, while the domain registrar recommends DNS forwarding.  What would be the benefits of one over the other, or does it really not matter (much)?

---

To attempt to clarify, in response to comments:

I have two domain names (eg abc.com and xyz.com), registered through a company that does both domains and hosting but I only have the domains registered there, not hosted. They are both then hosted by another hosting company (both the same company), but one domain name has (I think it's called) A-Record pointing to IP addresses on the host, the other has NS-records pointing to the webhost's Name servers.

In the picture above, the orange one is the one where NS records are pointing to the webhosts Nameservers, the blue has A-records pointing to the webhost (but the NS-records are using the registrar's Nameservers)

Comment: so I think your registrar has made some confusing terminology choices, and that may be clouding the matter. Am i correctly understanding that you have two domains (zones), and one is hosted by a DNS  server on your network periphery, but the other is hosted by the registrar on their servers. is that correct? in your image, which one of the two configurations you display is the one where you host the server yourself?

Comment: @FrankThomas - I have two domain names (eg abc.com and xyz.com), registered through a company that does both domains and hosting but I only have the domains registered there, not hosted.  They are both then hosted by another hosting company (both the same company), but one domain name has (I think it's called) A-Record pointing to IP addresses on the host, the other has NS-records pointing to the webhost's Name servers.  Does that make more sense now?

Comment: @FrankThomas In the picture, the orange one is the one where NS records are pointing to the webhosts Nameservers, the blue has A-records pointing to the webhost (but the NS-records are using the registrar's Nameservers)

Comment: ahh ok, so you are just debating whether to host your zone on the registrars severs or on the webhosts servers. so then i'd ask myself, which one am I more likely to stop doing business with at some point in the future (the registrar or the webhost). since you are contemplating changing web hosts, I'd move your zone to the registrar, so that when you change web hosting services, you only need to repoint to the new IPs.

Comment: @FrankThomas Yes I guess that's it - I'm just trying to figure the pros and cons of each so I can choose which one is better for my situation

Comment: If it's literally just that the zones are managed in one place over the other then that works too

Comment: well, usually the thing people have to think about is whether to host the zone themselves on their own server. this has some advantages for advanced usages, but does make your infrastructure more complicated and takes more work to maintain. if its just a question of which remote company hosts your authorative zone, just pick the one you like working with better.